LLVM kCFI sanitizer with function of volatile arguments
Here is the minimal reproducible example:
// my_func.h
typedef volatile struct {
   int a;
} my_vdata_t;

typedef struct {
   int a;
} my_data_t;

extern void (*vfunc)(my_vdata_t* data);
extern void (*func)(my_data_t* data);

void init_func();

// my_func.c
#include "stdio.h"
#include "my_func.h"
void my_vfunc( my_vdata_t* data ) {
    printf("volatile a = %d\n", data->a);
}
void my_func( my_data_t* data ) {
    printf("a = %d\n", data->a);
}

void (*vfunc)(my_vdata_t*) = NULL;
void (*func)(my_data_t*) = NULL;

void init_func() {
    vfunc = my_vfunc;
    func = my_func;
}

// main.c
#include "stdio.h"
#include "my_func.h"

int main() {
    init_func();
    my_vdata_t my_vdata;
    my_vdata.a = 100;

    my_data_t my_data;
    my_data.a = 200;

    func(&my_data);
    vfunc(&my_vdata);
}

The original issue is from kernel code built with clang-16 and -fsanitize=kcfi but
my test environment is with clang-6 and -fsanitize=cfi-icall -flto instead.
clang -m32 -g -O3 -fsanitize=cfi-icall -flto -c my_func.c my_func.o
clang -m32 -g -O3 -fsanitize=cfi-icall -flto -c main.c main.o
clang -m32 -fsanitize=cfi-icall -flto -o test  main.o my_func.o

the error output:
a = 200 
Illegal instruction (core dumped)

As you can see, program exited with signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.
If I remove -fsanitize=cfi-icall -flto during compilation, the output is within expectation:
a = 200
volatile a = 100

without illegal instruction error.
This MRE is a bit different from my original case, but still confuses my a lot.
Looks like volatile keyword conflicts with -fsanitize=cfi-icall sanitizer.

Edit the question to provide a [mre]. This is not a [mre] because func = &my_func; is not valid at file scope, so it must appear inside some function, and you have not given any context for that, and because you have not shown the error emitted by the sanitizer.

Thanks for the recommendation. I've updated with more details.

This is issue 106593: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/106593
You can work round it by adding a tag to the struct type definiton:
typedef volatile struct my_vdata {
   int a;
} my_vdata_t;

